# Split lines with intersections

Tags: qgis, splitting, segment, transects

I basically want to divide this main line (LRS187) into several segments divided by points (LRSEvents187). I tried to use 'Split Lines at Points' tool from SAGA but got nowhere. I tried making intersection lines at these points, so to then use 'Split Lines with Lines' but to no use.

I'm not sure why but my intersection lines all have the same information at the attributes table but the are placed at their respective points, so when I try to split the main line (LRS187) with these intersections, it doesn't cut anything really.

[image: main line with intersection lines at the different points]

[image: Main Line I want to cut Attribute Table (distance)]
[image: Diferent points where I]

*Edit* Here is the attibute table resulting of the Shortest lines operation. As seen below, there doesn't seem to have any distance on the generated lines, so I can't continue with the operations.[image: Attributes table resulting of Shortest Lines to Features]

Answer (score 1):

1. **Shortest line between features**. The points as source layer, lines as destination. This will create a line between each point and its closest line.
   Set a maximum distance so points far away from any line are discarded. And max n. neighbors = 1
2. **Extend lines** to make the shortest line output a little bit longer in both ends to cross the line to split.
3. **Split with lines**, with the lines you want to split as input layer, and the extended lines as split layer.

[image]

Comment: Hello! Thank you for responding but the problem still persists as the generated lines from the 'Shortests lines to Features' have no distance (you can see on the edit on the problem above).

Comment: You can recalculate distances

Comment: I have tried to use 'Distance matrix' to generate points with distance but this problem still persists.